# Matrix Ring Rotation in Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, matrix, graph

This is a hacker rank problem (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/matrix-rotation-algo), need to rotate a matrix R times. 
Matrix is MxN

The solution I came up with rotates each ring (outer -> inner). However it is quite inefficient and it does not pass the test.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
def print_matrix(matrix)
    matrix.each do |a|
        a.each do |n|
            print "#{n} "
        end
        puts 
    end
    puts
end

def rotate_ring(matrix,s_i,s_j,m,n)
    rotated = matrix.inject([]) { |a,element| a << element.dup }
    for i in (s_i...m)
        for j in (s_j...n)
            case [i,j]
                # Move items on corners
                #Top Left Corner
                when [s_i,s_j]
                    rotated[i+1][j] = matrix[i][j]
                #Bottom Left Corner
                when [m-1,s_j]
                    rotated[i][j+1] = matrix[i][j]
                #Bottom Right Corner
                when [m-1,n-1]
                    rotated[i-1][j] = matrix[i][j]
                #Top Right Corner
                when [s_i,n-1]
                    rotated[i][j-1] = matrix[i][j]
                ##################  
                # Move other items
                # Top Row
                when proc{|i,j| i == s_i and j>0 }
                    rotated[i][j-1] = matrix[i][j]
                # Bottom Row
                when proc{|i,j| i == m-1}
                    rotated[i][j+1] = matrix[i][j]
                # Left Column
                when proc{|i,j| i >= 0 and j == s_j}
                    rotated[i+1][j] = matrix[i][j]
                # Right Column
                when proc{|i,j| i >= 0 and j == n-1}
                rotated[i-1][j] = matrix[i][j]
            end
        end
    end
    return rotated
end

def rotate_matrix(matrix,m,n,r)
    s_i = 0
    s_j = 0
    min = ([m,n].min)/2
    r.times do
        for t in 0...min
            matrix = rotate_ring(matrix,0+t,0+t,m-t,n-t)
        end
    end
    return matrix
end

matrix = [['a','b','c','d'],
          ['e','f','g','h'],
          ['i','j','k','l'],
          ['m','n','o','p'],    
          ['q','r','s','t']]

m = matrix.size
n = matrix[0].size

print_matrix(matrix)
print_matrix(rotate_matrix(matrix,m,n,1))
```

Answer (score 2):

**Code**

```
def rotate_rings(arr, n)
  m = arr.transpose.transpose
  n.times { rotate_rings_once(m) }
  m
end

def rotate_rings_once(arr)
  nrings = (arr.size/2)
  m = arr.transpose.transpose
  4.times do
    nrings.times { |i| arr[i][i..-i-1] = m[i][i+1..-i-1] << m[i+1][-i-1] }
    rotate_array!(arr)
    rotate_array!(m)
  end
end

def rotate_array!(arr)
  arr.replace(arr.map!(&:reverse).transpose)
end
```

**Examples**

```
arr = [['a','b','c','d'],
       ['e','f','g','h'],
       ['i','j','k','l'],
       ['m','n','o','p'],    
       ['q','r','s','t']]

rotate_rings(arr, 0)
  #=> [["a", "b", "c", "d"],
  #    ["e", "f", "g", "h"],
  #    ["i", "j", "k", "l"],
  #    ["m", "n", "o", "p"],
  #    ["q", "r", "s", "t"]] 
rotate_rings(arr, 1)
  #=> [["b", "c", "d", "h"],
  #    ["a", "g", "k", "l"],
  #    ["e", "f", "o", "p"],
  #    ["i", "j", "n", "t"],
  #    ["m", "q", "r", "s"]] 
rotate_rings(arr, 2)
  #=> [["c", "d", "h", "l"],
  #    ["b", "k", "o", "p"],
  #    ["a", "g", "n", "t"],
  #    ["e", "f", "j", "s"],
  #    ["i", "m", "q", "r"]]
```

```
arr = [[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20]]

rotate_rings(arr, 0)
  #=> [[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
  #    [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
  #    [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
  #    [16, 17, 18, 19, 20]] 
rotate_rings(arr, 1)
  #=> [[ 2,  3,  4,  5, 10],
  #    [ 1,  8,  9, 14, 15],
  #    [ 6,  7, 12, 13, 20],
  #    [11, 16, 17, 18, 19]]
rotate_rings(arr, 2)
  #=> [[ 3,  4,  5, 10, 15],
  #    [ 2,  9, 14, 13, 20],
  #    [ 1,  8,  7, 12, 19],
  #    [ 6, 11, 16, 17, 18]]
```

**Notes:**

1. `rotate_array!` is helper method that rotates its argument (an array) counterclockwise, in place. For example:

   ```
   m = [[10, 11, 12, 13],
        [14, 15, 16, 17],
        [18, 19, 20, 21],
        [22, 23, 24, 25],
        [26, 27, 28, 20]] 

   rotate_array!(m)
     #=> [[13, 17, 21, 25, 20],
     #    [12, 16, 20, 24, 28],
     #    [11, 15, 19, 23, 27],
     #    [10, 14, 18, 22, 26]]`
   ```

The return value of `rotate_array!` is also the new value of its argument `m`. If we rotate `4` times, we get back to the original array.

2. The purpose of:

   ```
   m = arr.transpose.transpose
   ```

is to make a deep copy of `arr` so the latter will not be mutated. I could alternatively have used:

```
    m = arr.dup.map(:&dup)
```

3. In `rotate_rings_once(arr)`,

   ```
   nrings = (arr.size/2)
   ```

is the number of rings in the array. The top-left element of ring `i` (`i = 0, 1,..., nrings-1)`) is `arr[i][i]`. For each ring `i`, the top row of the ring is computed with the expression:

```
    arr[i][i..-i-1] = m[i][i+1..-i-1] << m[i+1][-i-1]
```

where `m` is a deep copy of `arr` that is computed before any shifting of elements of `arr` is performed.

The arrays `arr` and `m` are then rotated and the elements of the (new) top row of of each ring in `arr` are shifted. These calculations are repeated three more times.

Comment: Thanks @Cary I really appreciate you taking the time to answer. I am trying to follow your solution, but it doesn't seem to give the correct answer. The picture: [Matrix Rotation](https://hr-challenge-images.s3.amazonaws.com/2517/matrix-rotation.png) shows how the matrix should rotate. My code works, its just inefficient, I was hoping for some tips to improve it.

Comment: I'll have another look when I have some time.